# Add the data of MaterialInwardHeader and MaterialDetails in StockDetails through enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am working on Point Of Sale project.
I want to Create StockDetails report.

1. I have Created two tables `MaterialInwardHeader` and  `MaterialInwardDetails`.
2. I want add the details of both the tables through `enum` in `StockDetails` table.
3. Here is the following code provided of `MaterialInwardHeader` and `MaterialInwardDetails`.

```
public class AddMaterialInward
{
    public record AddMaterialInwardCommand : ICreateCommand<AddMaterialInwardCommand.AddMaterialInwardModel, bool>
    {
        public AddMaterialInwardModel Model { get; init; } = default!;
        public record AddMaterialInwardModel(Guid PurchaseOrderId,
                                             Guid VendorId,
                                             DateTime Date,
                                             IList<MaterialInwardDetailsModel> MaterialInwardDetail);

        public record MaterialInwardDetailsModel(Guid ProductId,
                                                 float Quantity,
                                                 DateTime ExpiryDate);

        internal class Validator : AbstractValidator<AddMaterialInwardCommand>
        {
            public Validator()
            {
                RuleFor(r => r.Model.PurchaseOrderId).NotEmpty().WithMessage("PurchaseOrderId is required.");
                RuleFor(r => r.Model.Date).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Date is required.");
                RuleFor(r => r.Model.MaterialInwardDetail).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Details are required.");
            }
        }
        public class Handler : IRequestHandler<AddMaterialInwardCommand, ResultModel<bool>>
        {
            private readonly IRepository<MaterialInwardHeader> _materialInwardHeaderRepository;
            private readonly IRepository<MaterialInwardDetails> _materialInwardDetailsRepository;

            public Handler(IRepository<MaterialInwardHeader> materialInwardHeaderRepository, IRepository<MaterialInwardDetails> materialInwardDetailsRepository)
            {
                _materialInwardHeaderRepository = materialInwardHeaderRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(materialInwardHeaderRepository));
                _materialInwardDetailsRepository = materialInwardDetailsRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(materialInwardDetailsRepository));
            }

            public async Task<ResultModel<bool>> Handle(AddMaterialInwardCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                if (request == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
                var materialInwardHeader = new MaterialInwardHeader
                {
                    PurchaseOrderId = request.Model.PurchaseOrderId,
                    VendorId = request.Model.VendorId,
                    Date = request.Model.Date
                };

                var response = await _materialInwardHeaderRepository.AddAsync(materialInwardHeader);

                foreach (var item in request.Model.MaterialInwardDetail)
                {
                    var result = await _materialInwardDetailsRepository.AddAsync(MaterialInwardDetails.Create(materialInwardHeader.Id,
                                                                                                              item.ProductId,
                                                                                                              item.Quantity,
                                                                                                              item.ExpiryDate));
                    response.MaterialInwardDetails.Add(result);
                }
                return ResultModel<bool>.Create(true);
            }


        }
    }
```

4. When I add data to MaterialInward It should also store data in `StockDetails` through `enum` .
5. Enum
   `{ Purchase = 1, Return   = 2, Sale    = 3 }`
6. Following is StockDetails Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."StockDetails"
(
    Id           uuid                     NOT NULL,
    RefId        uuid                     NOT NULL,
    ProductId    uuid                     NOT NULL,
    Quantity     real                     NOT NULL,
    QuantityType integer                  NOT NULL,
    Rate         real                     NOT NULL,
    Created      timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    Updated      timestamp with time zone,
    RecordStatus integer                  NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_StockDetails PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

7. Here `RefId = MaterialInwardHeaderId , ProductId = ProductId from MaterialInwardDetails, Quantity = Quantity From MaterialInwardDetails` It should add Data in StockDetails through provide Enums.

Would someone give me an example code or documentation to go through. I am a fresher and I am finding it quite difficult to get the right documentation for it.

Comment: Please format your post - it's difficult to read.

Comment: Also, please post **actual** `CREATE TABLE` statements instead of a textual description of your tables (you can get the `CREATE TABLE` statements from SSMS's Objext Explorer).

Comment: @Dai I have edited the Post and provided following code could you help me with the documentation for it or example code for the following

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "_it should also store data in StockDetails through enum_" - that statement makes no sense: an enum type is just a number, it can't do anything by itself...

Comment: @Dai It means If it is Type 1 which is Purchase It should Insert the data as Purchase , If it is Type 2 which is Sale It should Insert the data as Sale , If it is Type 3 It should insert data as Return

Comment: @Dai any documentation for Point Of Sale in .Net?